# Wordpress Mod Rewrite Same Server

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I've been researching this for got to be around 6 hours now (had I known I'd spend this long I would have read the manual from start to finish to learn things in-depth) and out of desperation I'm finally asking.

I have a client with two Wordpress sites.

www.myoldsite.com and www.mynewsite.com.

www.myoldsite.com is hosted on a server I can't access while I have access to www.mynewsite.com.

Because of this restraint I've decided to use a .htaccess file on www.mynewsite.com to handle specific 301 redirects and point the domain www.myoldsite.com to www.mynewsite. Most of the redirects are working without any issues but there are a few that aren't. I know why but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
For example:
On the www.myoldsite.com they had the page www.myoldsite.com/about-us. 
On the new site the new URL is www.mynewsite.com/about-us/what-we-do.
```

The htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mynewsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mynewsite\.com$
RewriteRule /about-us "http\:\/\/mynewsite\.com\/about\-us\/what\-we\-do\/" [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

At the moment this causes the recursive error "too many redirects". If I change the Rewrite Rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^/about-us$ "http\:\/\/mynewsite\.com\/about\-us\/what\-we\-do\/" [R=301,L]
```

The URL www.myoldsite.com/about-us returns a 404 /index.php not found. This I can tell is coming from Wordpress.

All I need www.myoldsite.com/about-us to point to www.mynewsite.com/about-us/what-we-do using a redirect. If anyone can assist that would be most helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `RewriteRule` is awfully long.  I just successfully did the following with no fuss:

```
RewriteRule ^about-us(/?)$ https://www.google.com/about/ [R=301,L]
```

I think the forward-slash at the beginning of `about-us` in your rule is causing a problem.

Also, I'm not 100% sure whether or not browsers cache these redirects, but I've had some trouble in the past with Firefox and 301 redirects where after a change Firefox's behavior continued as before the change and opening a new browser (Safari) worked.  You might check into that.

Comment: Oh my goodness. You're a genius. It was simply the leading /. God one of those things that I just didn't notice. Spent so much time looking for something else.